# Manipulate Callback URL in AWS Cognito using aws cli command

Tags: shell, aws-cli, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I want to modify the existing callback url in my `aws cognito` using `aws cli` command (From shell script).

Below command i am using to describe the user-pool client.

```
aws cognito-idp describe-user-pool-client --user-pool-id us-west-2_asASD24d --client-id asdfasdf546a5s4df --region us-west-2
```

Now i want to check that my url is available in callback url or not. If not then add this url in callback url.

I can achieve this using below command.

```
aws cognito-idp describe-user-pool-client --user-pool-id us-west-2_asASD24d --client-id asdfasdf546a5s4df --region us-west-2 --callback-urls <value>
```

But i don't know how to manipulate the existing callback url in shell script.

> And should give every parameter while updating the user-pool-client?

I tried to update the callback-url using below command and my remaining all settings get removed.

```
aws cognito-idp update-user-pool-client --user-pool-id us-west-2_peANXssz7 --client-id 22d80r9fh1oh80i5pc5vuc63br --region us-west-2 --callback-urls '["https://test-jdtest.dev.com?oauth=callback",]'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This one works.

```
ExistingCallbackUrls=$(aws cognito-idp describe-user-pool-client --user-pool-id $CognitoPoolId --client-id $CognitoClientId --region $AWS_REGION --output text | grep CALLBACKURLS | awk '{print $2}')

YourUrl=https://example.com

NewCallbackUrls="$ExistingCallbackUrls $YourUrl"

aws cognito-idp update-user-pool-client --user-pool-id $CognitoPoolId --client-id $CognitoClientId --callback-urls $NewCallbackUrls --region $AWS_REGION
```

Comment: Have you checked other values of this user-pool-client? 
We have to pass all other existing values as well. Otherwise, it will get removed and we will see only the callback urls.